# Value for key at index

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in my php:

```
 Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [catId] => 0
        [catName] =>0
        [hasSubCategory] => 0 
        [hasSubView] => 0 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [catId] => 1020 
        [catName] => apple 
        [hasSubCategory] => 0 
        [hasSubView] => 1 
    )
    [2] => Array ( 
        [catId] => 1040 
        [catName] => orange
        [hasSubCategory] => 1 
        [hasSubView] => 0 
    )
```

How can I print the catName.value where catId.value = 1040?

In this case the output should be 'orange';

Comment: Array structure is un-readable, please format it better..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach($arr as $v)
{
  if($v['catId']==1040)
  {
    echo $v['catName'];
    break;
  }
}
```

I hope it will will help.

Comment: +1 OP didn't explicitly say that he want to output only one value, so at least add a comment for the `break;`. ;-)

Comment: Yes I needed only one value. :) thanks again. I LOVE STACKOVERFLOW

Comment: @Basti: I thought it was obviously :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($array['0']['catId'] == 1040): print_r($array['0']['catName']) endif;
```